# join iterable error when joining str and int

Tags: python, join, iterable

I am trying to write a Battleship game with the numbers 1-10 in the first row and the letter "o" in the another 10. Unfortunately, I can't join the numbers because an error "can only join an iterable" keeps flashing.

Can you tell me how to fix it?

```
board = list(range(10))

for x in range(10):
    board.append(["O"] * 10)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print (" ".join(row))

print_board(board)
```

Comment: Trying printing `board` *before* the error happens - hint: it's not what you think it is. You *really* should learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

Your fundamental problem is that your top row is not a list of lists, thus when you append to it, you are not getting what you had in mind.

But it is a bit unclear what you were after.  Did you want strings in the entire matrix, or integers in the top row?

**All strings:**

```
board = [[str(n) for n in range(1, 11)]] + [list('0'*10)] * 10

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print (" ".join(row))

print_board(board)
```

**Integers in the top row:**

```
board = [range(1, 11)] + [list('0' * 10)] * 10

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print (" ".join(str(x) for x in row))

print_board(board)
```

**Results:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```